# how to give validation in javascript where only numbers are allowed to enter in prompt box?

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
 var ratioChange = prompt('Are you sure to change seller ration of this user?');
                if(ratioChange != "")
                {
                  $('#clsdywusers_hdnaction').val("SET_SELLER_RATIO");
                  $('#clsdywusers_seller_ratio').val(ratioChange);
                }
                else
                {
                  alert('Please enter seller ratio.');
                  return false;
                }
```

Now here what I want is that I only want to allow users to write digits in prompt box.Please help.

Comment: You cant. The best you can do is create your own popup with validation, or test the returned value and repeat the prompt if its not valid

Comment: This has been asked before.

Please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539237/javascript-prompt-textbox-only-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript input **keypress** event and check for every typed character if it's a number or not:

```
    function is_numeric(val){
        if(val > 47 && val < 58) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    $(".your_input").keypress(function(e){

            switch(e.which){
                    // exclude left and right navigation arrows from check
                case 0: case 8:break;
                default:
                    if(is_numeric(parseInt(e.which))) return true;
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
            }
    });
```

**Update:** with prompt

```
    var ratioChange = prompt('Are you sure to change seller ration of this user?');
    if(ratioChange != "" && is_number(ratioChange))
    {
       $('#clsdywusers_hdnaction').val("SET_SELLER_RATIO");
       $('#clsdywusers_seller_ratio').val(ratioChange);
    }
    else
    {   
        alert('Please enter seller ratio.');
        return false;
    }

    function is_numeric(val){
        if(val > 47 && val < 58) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    function is_number(val){
        var value= new String(val), singleNumber;
        for(var i=0; i < value.length; i++){
            singleNumber = 48 + parseInt(value[i]);
            if(!is_numeric(singleNumber)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[JSBIN](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr5A8/)

Comment: In this case, you can't have full control on your `prompt` dialog, for this you can use a modal dialog, but if you really want it with `prompt` the only control you can do is to check the final value given by the client.